# How to compile fips for mingw compiler?

Tags: openssl, mingw, msys, fips

I am trying to compile Fips module 2.0 for mingW compiler.I have installed mingW, msys and  downloaded openssl-fips-2.0.16 . I entered ./config fips in msys to configure it for mingw and after that entered make command in msys and got this errors:

> cryptlib.c:260:20: error: 'ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER' undeclared
>   (first use in this function)   GetLastError() !=
>   ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)

How can I solve this issue? What is the correct way to do this for mingW compiler?

Comment: GOT the solution  fixed this by downgrading MinGW's w32api:                     
 **mingw-get upgrade "w32api<5.0.2"** This link:https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/5327

Comment: If you've found a working solution, add it as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution..fixed this by downgrading MingW's w32api 
(mingw-get upgrade "w32api<5.0.2")

Refer this : github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/5327